# Having array of values for ionic range

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic2, range

I'm having trouble using ionic range, I want it to have non linear value such as:
 0 - 10 - 20 - 30 - 40 etc... 
But more like: 
50 - 100 - 200 - 300 - 400 - 500 - 1000 - 1500 etc... 
Like a **specific array of values**.
Is it possible or how can I call a .ts method at each movement to dynamically change the steps while moving the the knob(s)?
many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to custom your steps, but there's a workaround you can use. Let's say you have the following array `[50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 1500]`, you can use a function on your range change to select a value in this array based in the value you have in your range:

```
<!-- -->
<ion-badge>{{customSteps}}</ion-badge>
  <ion-item>
    <!-- YOUR max WILL'BE YOUR ARRAY LENGTH - 1 TO GET THE LAST VALUE POSITION -->
    <ion-range min="0" [max]="rangeArray.length - 1" [(ngModel)]="range" (ionChange)="watchRange()" color="secondary">
    <ion-label range-left>50</ion-label>
    <ion-label range-right>1500</ion-label>
  </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

In your .ts:

```
range: number = 0;
customSteps: any;
rangeArray: any[] = [50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 1500];

constructor(){
  // INITIALIZE YOUR RANGE VALUE
  this.watchRange();
}

watchRange(){
  // IN THIS METHOD YOU'LL CHANGE YOUR customSteps VALUE USING THE RANGE VALUE TO GET
  //A VALUE IN YOUR ARRAY POSITION. customSteps WILL BE USED FOR PRESENTATION AND IN YOUR OTHER METHODS
  this.customSteps = this.rangeArray[this.range];
}
```

Hope this helps.